# How do I use <stop_token> in macOS?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, clang

Consider the following MRE:

```cpp
#include <stop_token>

int main() {
    std::stop_source ssource;
}
```

With the following C++ compiler build settings:
[image]

this code emits the following error if I try to compile it with the latest "stable" Xcode in macOS (Version 14.0):

> 'stop_token' file not found

Which is weird because the same works flawlessly when [checking in the compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Wvv3a8vn4).

I also tried to compile the file from command line but to no avail:

```
% clang++ -std=c++20 main.cpp
main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'stop_token' file not found
#include <stop_token>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

The same is for `-std=c++2b` option.

Is this header located in some other (say, experimental) subdirectory in macOS?

Comment: Apple clang tends to lag behind 'regular' clang, that's probably the issue here

Comment: @PaulSanders that might be true, but clang has been supporting this header since about 4-5 major versions ago

Comment: According [to this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20#C.2B.2B14_library_features) Clang do not support that library feature yet. (both Clangs regular and Apple).

Comment: libstdc++ (clang's default) has support for it, but MacOS clang uses libc++, which doesn't. As far as I can tell, Apple's clang hasn't supported libstdc++ for years.

Comment: @molbdnilo You're right (I just checked, just to be sure), Apple's clang does not support libstdc++.  As you say, they dropped it ages ago.  PS: Make that an answer, why don't you.

Comment: @molbdnilo do you mind turning your comment into an answer?